# Usign the Amp Cdn url

Tags: cdn, amp-html

I installed an amp plugin on my wordpress site.
When I search on Google, google cached my home page, but when I click on other pages, it goes directly to the amp page, that is, not the cached page.
How can I present the whole site on google cdn?
When people click on any link on my home page, I want to see a url structure like "https://example-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/example.com/example-category". How can I achieve this?
I'm waiting for your help. Thank you from now.

Answer (score 0):

When I log in to my site via google, it opens from google cache.  When I log in to the site, when I click on any link, it opens from my amp page, not from the cache.  I want this to be unlocked from cache.  like mersinbi-com.cdn.ampproject.org